# Select button pulling wrong info on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regular select box on my site.
Then using javascript I pull the val after a click

```
 $('#r_frequency').click(function(){
    if( $('#r_frequency').val() == 'm') {
       frequency = 12;
    } else{
         frequency = 4;
    }
    alert(frequency );
```

On a computer, when I click m, I get 12, otherwise, I get a 4.
For some strange reason , on a mobile (not an emulator), when I click m, my alert says 4, and vice versa.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please post your markup as well. are you trying to alert the value of the select before it is changed or the new value after it has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be getting the selected option, try target the selected element with a css selector like this:

```
$( "#r_frequency option:selected" ).val()
```

Comment: I switched it to that, but it's still pulling the wrong choice